# unknown part of hardware at 90º need help to identify

Tags: hardware-failure, temperature

One of the temperature sensors is showing 90º. The problem is I don't know what piece of hardware is it showing... I'm adding a screenshot.

I think is not from the CPU...

[image]

Comment: Is something actually going wrong with your computer that makes you think this is a problem, or have you just seen this and decided that there is a problem?

Comment: I'd say you are getting a bogus reading, which is all to common with many sensors.

Comment: One fan shows a read-out of 0%. Is there any fan located in the system that is not rotating?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it the temperature of a single sensor. The CPU temperatures are well within specification.  You would have to use a heat gun to determine what area of the motherboard is warmer then the rest to identify where the sensor is.

Comment: the fans are going crazy from a month ago.... when everything started to slow down

Comment: Fans going crazy usually means lots of processes or processes using a lot of resources. Subsequent slowing down most likely means there are processes still using resources. You should backup your data and do a clean install of your OS, you may have a virus or other unwanted application running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=254668.0) it's the northbridge but seemingly it is fine at those temperatures.  If you really want to bring it down you can install more fans or add a better heatsink to the chip (if possible).